# What is the meaning of "This Department has worked _ days without a lost time accident"?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

What does this sentence mean? Does it mean that no unfortunate event happened? What would that event mean? A fight?

Comment: It's a legal/technical usage.  Safety laws require companies to report on-the-job injuries, and, above a certain frequency/severity (or where company negligence is a contributing factor) fines can result.  So many companies "campaign" to keep such injuries to a minimum.

Comment: Can anyone enlighten me why it's getting down voted? 
The phrase " A LOST TIME ACCIDENT" seems incomprehensible English.

Comment: Waqas, there are at least two possible reasons for downvotes here. (1) The title is in capitals, which is regarded as *shouting* (not very courteous). (2) You haven't included any evidence of research, as required (see [ask]). An internet search for "lost time accident" produces immediate clear answers, which is why I'm voting to close your question for lack of research. For further guidance, take the EL&U [Tour]. :-)

Comment: @Chappo Why not delete the question since it does not offer any contribution? It's not letting me do it The title was bold because this sign is always capitalized on the boards, and you can always edit it (It's not a down vote reason). The phrase " A LOST TIME ACCIDENT" do not produce immediate clear answer on the search, maybe for you because you are already a native speaker. And this phrase doesn't seems grammatical.

Answer (score 2):

It means nobody's gotten hurt so badly they missed work.

It's usually used in factories or other workplaces where there's a real risk of injury if you don't follow appropriate precautions when doing your job.